# JIRA search query - how could I use 'status changed' to have 'after startOfDay' + fixed HH:mm?

Tags: date, search, jira

I am trying to create a filter for the Dashboard. The idea is to show the list of issues being processed within particular time each day (e.g. 9:00-10:00). What I currently have is:

```
project = "Project_name" AND status changed by user_name before "2010-02-12 10:00" after "2010-02-12 09:00"  ORDER BY id
```

The problem is I have to manually update filter each day - is there any workaround? Ideally would be to have separate marker for `startOfDay` and for `HH:mm` - but there's no such option in JIRA as far as I know...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use startOfDay() and endOfDay() passing hours shift. From 9AM to 9PM:

```
before endOfDay(-3h) after startOfDay(9h)
```

Docs: https://confluence.atlassian.com/display/JIRA/Advanced+Searching

Comment: Of course! How could I omit that! Thanks a lot! That totally solves my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Yep agree, you dont have any direct option.

```
CHANGED
The "CHANGED" operator is used to find issues that
have a value which had changed for the specified field.

This operator has the following optional predicates:

•AFTER "date"
•BEFORE "date"
•BY "username"
•DURING ("date1","date2")
•ON "date"
•FROM "oldvalue"
•TO "newvalue"
```

So you may need to consider any plugins possibly around atlassian forums